# Landingpages different languages

Tags: magento

I have a magento website with 3 languages
English
Netherlands
Germany.

My question is I want that German peoplo go to the the german languages page, and the english to the english languages page.

Comment: you will check country using user ip after that set your language on for particular store.

Comment: I get that but where and how?

Answer (score 0):

```
     <?php

        define("GEOIP_DAT_FILE", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/geoip/GeoIP.dat");
        define("GEOIP_INC_FILE", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/geoip/geoip.inc");

        include(GEOIP_INC_FILE);

        $_geoip = geoip_open(GEOIP_DAT_FILE ,GEOIP_STANDARD);
        $_country_code = geoip_country_code_by_addr($_geoip, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        geoip_close($_geoip);

        switch ($_country_code) { 
          case "GB": // United Kingdom
            $_SERVER["MAGE_RUN_CODE"] = "uk";
            break;
          case "AU": // Australia
            $_SERVER["MAGE_RUN_CODE"] = "au";
            break;
          case "NZ": // New Zealand
            $_SERVER["MAGE_RUN_CODE"] = "nz";
            break;
          default:
            $_SERVER["MAGE_RUN_CODE"] = "base";
        }

        ?>
Please use this code it will help to you, for complete your task, also  please see this link: http://rosskendall.com/blog/web/using-geoip-with-magento-and-multiple-sites
```